# Merge table data

Tags: oracle

```
Table1               Table2                 Table3           Table4
Sl Name City       index len bre       col tax income      price dicount org
1  ABC   XYZ       1     10   12       1   23   40          1   10      XYZ
2  DEF   asd       2     12   14       2   24   42          2   6       asd
3  ghi   jkl                           3   78   89          3    0      gah
```

These entries correspond to respective tables. I want to fetch data from all 4 tables irrespective of whether values are present in Table2 or not. Any null value in Table2 should not hamper the output.

```
select tab1.Name,
        tab2.len,
        tab3.tax,
        tab4.org
From Table1  tab1,
     Table2  tab2, 
     Table3  tab3,   
     Table4  tab4
where tab1.sl=tab2.index(+)
AND      tab2.index(+)=tab3.col
AND   tab3.col=tab4.price;
```

This query only returns results for those Sl for which there is entry in table 2. How can I resolve this?

Comment: mysql doesnt support (+) looks to me you are using oracle database

Comment: Please show us your desired output.  It is not completely clear to me what you are trying to do.  And yes, the `(+)` join syntax looks like Oracle and you should not be using it anyway.

Comment: If you are using this inside a `merge` statement, then please include the full statement.

Answer (score 1):

To use a proper ANSI left join:

```
select tab1.Name,
        tab2.len,
        tab3.tax,
        tab4.org
From Table1  tab1  
     inner join Table3  tab3 on tab1.sl.tab3.col
     inner join Table4  tab4 on tab3.col=tab4.price
     left join Table2  tab2 on tab1.sl=tab2.index;
```

This makes your code much more readable.

Comment: The ANSI outer join syntax is way clearer than the old Oracle one.

Comment: Actually I'm writing a procedure and this select statement is inside Merge. Inside merge while executing procedure join will not work.

Comment: Hi Cgritton i need help forming a new query if possible could you help. I have posted that question फेव आवर्ज ago

Answer (score 0):

Try following ---

```
select tab1.Name,
        tab2.len,
        tab3.tax,
        tab4.org
From 
   Table1  tab1 left join Table2  tab2  
on tab1.sl=tab2.index(+) join Table3  tab3 
on tab2.index(+)=tab3.col join Table4  tab4 
on tab3.col=tab4.price;
```

Comment: Actually I'm writing a procedure and this select statement is inside Merge. Inside merge while executing procedure join will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Look, you should move from the 1990s into the early 2000s, by rewriting your query without the 'orrible omega-join `(+)` syntax.

Converting omega to `join`, your query comes out like this.

```
SELECT tab1.Name,
       tab2.len,
       tab3.tax,
       tab4.org
  FROM Table1  tab1,
 left  join  Table2  tab2 ON tab1.sl=tab2.index
 right join  Table3  tab3 ON tab2.index=tab3.col 
 inner join  Table4  tab4 ON tab3.col=tab4.price;
```

And, then the apparently chaotic combination of right, left, and inner join operations hints at the solution to your problem.

Change over to all left joins and your `Table1` rows won't be suppressed when they don't match other tables.

```
      SELECT tab1.Name,
             tab2.len,
             tab3.tax,
             tab4.org
        FROM Table1 tab1
   LEFT JOIN Table2 tab2 ON tab1.sl=tab2.index
   LEFT JOIN Table3 tab3 ON tab2.index=tab3.col 
   LEFT JOIN Table4 tab4 ON tab3.col=tab4.price;
```

Even if you must use the old omega join syntax, you should use it in a way which won't suppress rows from `Table1`

```
select tab1.Name,
        tab2.len,
        tab3.tax,
        tab4.org
From Table1  tab1,
     Table2  tab2, 
     Table3  tab3,   
     Table4  tab4
where tab1.sl=tab2.index(+)
AND   tab2.index=tab3.col(+)
AND   tab3.col=tab4.price(+);
```

The position of the `(+)` on the right means it's a left join, and vice versa.

Comment: Actually I'm writing a procedure and this select statement is inside Merge. Inside merge while executing procedure join will not work.

Comment: *Of course* join operations work in merge statements. You just don't have the syntax correct yet. In any case, see my edit. Your join configuration is suppressing mismatched rows from the wrong tables.